# Не получается передать функцию из useState в компонент

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Есть у меня главный компонент App.js, сделал в нём что то типа бд. Хочу что бы объект авторизированного пользователя находился внутри App.js, создал useState, в котором хочу хранить этого пользователя.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import './App.css';
import AuthPage from './components/AuthPage/AuthPage';

function App() {
  const [activeUser, setActiveUser] = useState();  
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(
    [
      {
        name: 'Andrey',
        email: 'qwerty@mail.ru',
        password: 'qwerty'
      },
      {
        name: 'Roma',
        email: 'ramenCisco@mail.ru',
        password: '123'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ilya',
        email: 'ilyazxc@mail.ru',
        password: 'zxc'
      }
    ]

  )

  return (
    <>
      <AuthPage users = {users} setActiveUser = {setActiveUser}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Для того что бы поместить туда пользователя мне надо что бы он сначала авторизировался, для этого у меня есть компонент AuthPage.js, в котором находится Login.js, через который я в свою очередь и собираюсь передавать объект с авторизированным пользователем прямиком в state App.js, для этого передаю с помощью props мою функцию setActiveUser из App.js сначала в AuthPage.js а потом из AuthPage.js в Login.js

`AuthPage.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

import './AuthPage.css'

export default function AuthPage(users, setActiveUser){
    return (
        <div className='auth-block'>
            <Login users = {users} setActiveUser = {setActiveUser}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

В Login.js я сначала проверяю формы, а потом уже пытаюсь готовый объект передать в state с помощью setActiveUser(obj)

`Login.js`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import './Login.css';

function Login({users, setActiveUser}){        


            setStatus(<p className='succes'>Пользователь успешно авторизирован</p>);
            console.log(typeof(setActiveUser));
            setActiveUser({name: 'da'});
}
```

Большую часть кода вырезал ибо там идёт просто проверка форм, а это уже конечный результат у меня должен был быть, но что то пошло не так: `Uncaught TypeError: setActiveUser is not a function`.
Проверил мой объект с пользователем на тип данных с помощью typeof, получился `object`

Начал проверять тип данных самой функций setActiveUser, получил `object`, проверил деструктуризацию,вроде всё в норме, попробовал в `Auth.page` при приёме аргументов тоже деструктуризировать setActiveUser из App.js и потом передать:

```
export default function AuthPage(users, {setActiveUser}){}
```

по итогу в Login.js через typeof(setActiveUser) вообще получаю `indefined`

Может кто подсказать где я намудрил? Вообще понять не могу в чём дело

Answer (score 0):

Забыл деструктуризировать props в AuthPage.js

```
export default function AuthPage({ users, setActiveUser }){
    return (
        <div className='auth-block'>
            <Login users = {users} setActiveUser = {setActiveUser}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).